# Where is the "input point vector layer attribute" in the "Count Points in Polygon" in QGIS 2.18.9?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, statistics, point-in-polygon

In older QGIS versions the `Count Points in Polygon` vector analysis tool had an "input vector layer attribute to aggregate" to perform a statistical analysis (sum, mean, min, max) on the counted points in a polygon.

However, in the newer QGIS (using version 2.18.6) this tool has disappeared. Only the counts in polygon is present in the vector analysis and you can't select the attributes of the point layer anymore to perform a statistical analysis. The tool now only counts the points in the polygon without any analysis.

Does anyone has a solution where to find the statistical attribute analysis?

[image: figure = old count points in polygon with attribute selection]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, this feature is no more available from this processing tool.
But there is a tool that give you the opportunity to calculate SUM of Weight base on field value. It's called **"Count Point fro Polygon (weighted)"** processing tool.

Use the Weight field to calculate the SUM.

[image]

to get more statistics you should perform other actions :

1. use **Count Point in Polygon** and get the number of point in a new
   column.
2. with this two Colomn value you can calculate every stat you need from calculator.

Use ModelBuilder or script processing  to get it in one action.

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution. It's a pitty that the previous function is not available anymore. An extra motivation to dive into the ModelBuider.

Comment: your welcome, not a big deal to go throught ModelBuilder. please, don't forgot to mark my answer as you accepted it.

Comment: @Quake_K does this is the answer ？

Comment: So to know the mean value in a polygon one has to divide the weighted sum by the amount of points. Right ?

Comment: that's it, you right